apex dml in loop
can someone help me with my method logic i have a problem where Avoid running Soql and DML inside loops.
I tried to build a combined soql request englobe all the request and run it in one shot after the loop is finished by the Database.query(combinedSoql) but i did not find the solution
 public static Map<String, String> exDymcReq(
        List<String> listObjects,
        Map<String, String> filtersRequests,
        String offreOpportunite
    ) {
        Map<String, String> resultat = new Map<String, String>();
        List<RequestObjectWrapper> listRequestObjectWrapper = generatedListRequestObjectWrapper(listObjects, offreOpportunite);
        if (null != listRequestObjectWrapper && !listRequestObjectWrapper.isEmpty()) {
            for (RequestObjectWrapper requestObject : listRequestObjectWrapper) {
                String objectName = requestObject.objectName;
                Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
                set<String> setSelectFields = requestObject.selectFields;
                if (null != targetType) {
                    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeObjectResult = targetType.getDescribe();
                    if (!describeObjectResult.isCustomSetting()) {
                        String fielToFilter = requestObject.fielToFilter;
                        String fielFilter = requestObject.fielFilter;
                        //Dans le cas où il y a pas de fielFilter alors on ne réalise pas la requête pour éviter les limitsSalesforce
                        if (!String.isEmpty(fielFilter) && (filtersRequests.containsKey(fielFilter) || resultat.containsKey(fielFilter))) {
                            set<String> filterSet = new Set<String>();
                            if (filtersRequests.containsKey(fielFilter)) {
                                filterSet.add(filtersRequests.get(fielFilter));
                            } else {
                                filterSet.add(resultat.get(fielFilter));
                            }
                            List<String> selectFields = new List<String>();
                            selectFields.addAll(setSelectFields);
                            //Génération de la requête
                            **String requestSOQL = String.format(
                                'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} in :filterSet',
                                new List<String>{ String.join(selectFields, ','), objectName, fielToFilter }
                            );**

                            //Execution de la requête
                            **List<Sobject> result = Database.query(requestSOQL);**
                            if (null != result && !result.isEmpty()) {
                                for (String selectField : setSelectFields) {
                                    if (selectField.contains('.')) {
                                        List<String> fieldsSFDC = selectField.split('\\.');
                                        if (fieldsSFDC.size() == 2) {
                                            Sobject returnOject = result.get(0);
                                            if (null != returnOject.getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(0))) {
                                                resultat.put(
                                                    objectName + '.' + selectField,
                                                    String.valueOf(returnOject.getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(0)).get(fieldsSFDC.get(1)))
                                                );
                                            } else {
                                                resultat.put(objectName + '.' + selectField, '');
                                            }
                                        } else if (fieldsSFDC.size() == 3) {
                                            Sobject returnOject = result.get(0);
                                            if (
                                                null != returnOject.getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(0)) &&
                                                null != returnOject.getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(0)).getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(1))
                                            ) {
                                                resultat.put(
                                                    objectName + '.' + selectField,
                                                    String.valueOf(
                                                        returnOject.getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(0))
                                                            .getSobject(fieldsSFDC.get(1))
                                                            .get(fieldsSFDC.get(2))
                                                    )
                                                );
                                            } else {
                                                resultat.put(objectName + '.' + selectField, '');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        resultat.put(objectName + '.' + selectField, String.valueOf(result.get(0).get(selectField)));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Récupération d'un custom settings
                        if (CPQV10.equals(objectName)) {
                            CPQV10Settings__c cpq = CPQV10Settings__c.getInstance();
                            for (String selectField : setSelectFields) {
                                resultat.put(objectName + '.' + selectField, String.valueOf(cpq.get(selectField)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultat;
    }


You can only query one SObjectType at a time via the normal Ape API. So this is a case where querying inside a loop is legitimate, though it will fail if there are more than 100 types. (I'm assuming your RequestObjectWrapper objects have unique SObjectTypes; if not you could add logic to merge those queries.) If you need to support more than 100 types you will need to break the work up using e.g. a batchable.
The "don't query inside a loop" applies to the case where there is a loop that runs over an indeterminate number of records and there is a nested query for each of those records. That generally can be re-arranged using sets and maps to move the nested query into a single query following the loop. So a determinate number of queries - 2 - rather than an indeterminate number that might work to start with but that will fail with a governor limit as the number of records in the loop grows.
